# Does running both (XCode & Android Studio) at the same time overload my MacBook Air with only 8 GB of Ram

Tags: macos, xcode, memory, performance, android

This IDE is for the Automation Testing Purpose.

Along with Appium Server, I need to run the Emulator of Xcode's iOS Emulator and the Android Studio's Emulator.

Does this Run smoothly in the 8GB RAM of Macbook Air.

Comment: What do you mean by "Can I install"? "Do the installations conflict with each other", "Do I have enough space on my HDD/SSD", "Does running both at the same time lead to conflicts", "Does running both at the same time overload my system", or something different altogether? Please edit the question to add some details (also, what have you tried so far yourself).

Comment: @nohillside Does running both at the same time lead to conflicts/ or any overload

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can and should load up your machine and see how it behaves. I don't think you'll get an overload at all.

The activity monitor will tell you when you run into memory pressure and you can see if swap helps or if you have a workload that would save you time on different hardware.

I’ve still not replaced my 2015 MacBook with 256 NVMe SSD (blazingly fast storage when it was introduced and still in the ballpark on 2019 models for what I need)

[image: Developer Mac Specs]

I run mongodb, make single page web apps, design and test API and deployment scripts, package Mac software for enterprise distribution, sign apps, notarize apps and generally work / debug / program and develop on this machine. Yes, some newer hardware is faster on benchmarks but in real life, I'm the thing the computer is waiting on always in terms of getting meaningful work done and I know how to measure when I'm waiting for the computer and can then buy a different kit when (and only when) I know I'll save money or time with more horsepower or more RAM.

In fact, developing on this means my solutions run even faster since I know when I make a bad decision and memory isn't free and to make a better database query, better data structure, more elegant code rather than assuming everyone that runs my apps spent $4000 on their portable.

Comment: n.b. - I cheat, too. I have a Mac mini and Mac Pro that run remotely and my goal is to get things to CI as fast as possible, but I can and do run VM (which can be pokey don't run a VM the same time as building / debugging / emulating iOS) but constraints are good when you know why they are there.  Just get on with doing your thing and not obsessing prematurely if your tools can do the job. Pay attention, you will know when your tools are inadequate and then you can buy the right tools out of knowledge, not someone saying 8 GB of ram is/isn't enough even if that someone is me.

Answer (score 2):

You can install them both because installing only takes up disk space, not RAM. If you try to run them both simultaneously there may be a problem depending on how much RAM each application takes. They both may run simultaneously but they may be slow.

Comment: Bingo. And when it's slow, you can then make a change to how you work or justify the ROI to spend more. I made a much longer post, but I'm all in on "just do it" and learn to profile so you can buy strategically when you can save money by investing in better hardware.